# Is there a way to enable @Filter globally while taking logged in User ID as a parameter?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, filter, where-clause

I'm new to `@Filter` and I have understood that it takes in parameters when compared to `@Where`.

I have a use case where I need to filter the results for every end point based on the logged in `User`.

While searching for how to enable filtering globally, I came across a solution where AOP is used to intercept Session creation and to enable the filter which seems to be working fine.

The problem here is that I need to have the User ID sent in as the parameter while enabling the filter. How do I do it or is there any other alternative for this particular scenario?

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class EnableFilterAspect {

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "bean(entityManagerFactory) && execution(* createEntityManager(..))", 
            returning = "retVal")
    
    public void getSessionAfter(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object retVal) {
        
        if (retVal != null && EntityManager.class.isInstance(retVal)) {
            Session session = ((EntityManager) retVal).unwrap(Session.class);
            session.enableFilter("authorize").setParameter("userId", **USER_ID**);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you had solution for this case ?

Comment: @LoiNguyenTri This seemed to do the trick. `Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to store the user id in a thread local variable and use that in the aspect. Not sure what the filter does, but maybe multi-tenancy is more in line with what you want to achieve. The solution doesn't change much though, you will have to somehow publish the user id through a thread local variable.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class EnableFilterAspect {

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "bean(entityManagerFactory) && execution(* createEntityManager(..))", returning = "retVal")

    public void getSessionAfter(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object retVal) {

        if (retVal != null && EntityManager.class.isInstance(retVal)) {
            Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            if (auth != null && auth.isAuthenticated() && !(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
                Session session = ((EntityManager) retVal).unwrap(Session.class);
                session.enableFilter("authorize").setParameter("userId", ((UserPrincipal) auth.getPrincipal()).getId());
            }
        }
    }
}
```